# Are there any MySQL Benchmarking tools?

Tags: mysql, benchmark, configuration

I've heard a long time ago that there is this tool that helps you tweek mysql settings for better performance but i can't seam to find it. I am aware that I can use ab for apache to simulate high traffic and it will generate me a slow log. However, if it crashes (already happened and it was in production mode), I don't know why it crashed and if it can be tweeked from the config.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Benchmarking or Tuning tool?

IMHO, there's no tool that will be specific to the latter unless you have a super generic usage. You need to identify your usage pattern and tune your database hosts to accommodate. If you're write-heavy, you will have a different configuration than a read-heavy scenario. Bottom line, your tuning follows your applications usage.

For benchmarking, I use [Sysbench](http://sysbench.sourceforge.net/). Here's an example from my [blog](http://randymelder.com/2010/09/25/sysbench-for-mysql-burn-in-testing/).

Added:
Here's my beef with config tools: With the changes in versions 4.x vs 5.x vs 5.5.x there are a lot of tweaks that don't jive between them. So you really need a savvy DBA to evaluate what's going on for each host. Load, storage, traffic, application specific requirements, there's a lot that can go into an optimal configuration. A tool may get you part of the way, but may leave out something or include something that may cause a failure. From buffers to flushing to plugins to threading, a config tool may provide you with false confidence that you are implementing the correct config.

Comment: Sysbench would be a viable solution , mybench ( perls script ) would be too , however i'm more intrested in a tool that let's me know what settings should be tweeked as i'm not a DBA .

Comment: Adding to my answer.

Answer (score 4):

I think [MONyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/downloads.php#monyog) can handle some of your request.

> MONyog MySQL Monitor and Advisor is a
>   "MySQL DBA in a box" that helps MySQL
>   DBAs manage more MySQL servers, tune
>   their MySQL servers and fix problems
>   with MySQL database applications.

[image]
MONyog not only finds **problem SQL** it has 200+ monitors and advisors as well which suggests what parameter you should use for MySQL system variables (by editing `my.cnf/my.ini` file) this helps in fine-tune your MySQL server.

Further there are so many features that DBA would like to have in his day-to-day activites like trend report, Dashboard, Server config management, SNMP/SMTP alerts etc.. for more details you can refer this :

http://www.webyog.com/en/monyog_feature_list.php

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**Spotlight**](http://www.toadworld.com/MYSQL/SpotlightonMySQL/tabid/620/Default.aspx) a [**Toad**](http://www.toadworld.com/MYSQL/tabid/762/Default.aspx) application

> Spotlight® on MySQL diagnoses MySQL problems in real time by graphically displaying all database activity in an intuitive user interface, enabling you to respond quickly to issues that need attention.

Comment: quote from spotlight site: " ... With Spotlight on MySQL, DBAs or developers running Windows ... " , not realy suited as most web based app databases are on unix systems .

Comment: @poelinca - my bad! I think you should re-phrase your post to get more accurate information...

Comment: @poelinca: The target for Spotlight can be on any platform - Spotlight itself runs on Windows. We have TOAD running on Windows against Linux and Solaris DBs, no problems.

Comment: @Gaius: realy helpfull to know this, but in my case i would have to run it from my girlfriend pc ? , i don't own a pc/notebook/netbook that has windows installed .

Comment: Or run it in a VM or whatever. Is the cost of not fixing your problem greater than the cost of the tools and time to fix it, is the only question.

Answer (score 2):

Quest has a database benchmarking tool.  You can run a synthetic TPC-C, H, E test against your MySQL database.  It will not suggest configuration changes, but it does make testing those changes a bit easier.
[Benchmark Factory Community](http://benchmarkfactory.inside.quest.com/index.jspa)

Comment: Can you explain the mechanics of the test? How do we interpret it? A simple link to the community isn't very useful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your request could also be are there any tuning tools for MySQL?  There are serveral:

- phpMyAdmin Advisor
- MySQLTuner
- mysqlreport
- phpMyAdmin Advisor
- mysqltuner.pl

and some nice tuning suggestions at:
http://web3us.com/drupal6/how-create-web-site-handbook/how-setup-mysql/tuning-mysql

Comment: Jeff, try to provide some more details on the tools mentioned instead of just listing them off.